# Certbot unauthorized and connection errors

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a spring boot application on Google Cloud, CentOS 7. I wish to install SSL certificate via Let's Encrypt and Certbot. When I use `certbot --apache -d mydomain.zone` command I receive an error:
[image]

My domain is registered on Namecheap. My A records on Google Cloud:
[image]
Also I provided google cloud nameservers in Namecheap like in this tutorial: https://www.wpmentor.com/setup-domain-google-cloud-platform/

[image]

Can you tell me where the issue is? I also wonder is there an issue with my java code in app. For example sometimes while accessing index page, error_page is called. When I have a method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/error_page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homeError(Model model)
{
  return "/error_page";
}
```

I have a different certvbot error:

[image]

but when I comment/erase my controller method for error page I receive this error:

[image]

Can it be it's an application bug? Or issue with apache?

EDIT:
I tried to turn off Tomcat. Now I receive this error:
[image]

note: My Apache forwards to 8080, I don't know will it make any issue?

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port  8080
```

After `curl -I -L http://mydomain/.well-known/acme-challenge/zySNHSFB-qL95Ubx4jcIvuHPiiNbwkphE55kFuqP8jM:`

```
HTTP/1.1 302 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: /error_page
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 15 Feb 2022 20:01:50 GMT

HTTP/1.1 302 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: /error_page
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 15 Feb 2022 20:01:50 GMT

curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed
```

Comment: 1) Do not use images for text messages. 2) Your first problem is **Redirect loop detected**. This means your server responds with a **Location** header to redirect the client. The client goes to the new location and that redirect repeats over and over. That is the problem to fix. Use the command **curl -I -L URI** to debug.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it a lot.
I've edited the post, I copied what I got after curl -I -L command. I don't think there's anything suspicious here, but maybe I'm wrong. @JohnHanley

Comment: You must test the same URL that Let's Encrypt is calling.

Comment: ok, I fix that in the post. I'm getting plenty of 302 redirects. @JohnHanley

Comment: Delete everything in your question not related to the redirects. Then add details that show the server's configuration, etc that are related to redirecting clients. Fix the image issue otherwise, your question might get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to turn off the Apache web server to free my port 80. Also, I deleted `iptables` rule that forwards traffic from port 80 to port 8080. Now Certbot works